# How do you define the open interval $(a\times b , c\times d)$ for $a<c$; or when $a=c$, for $b<d$?

Tags: general-topology

On page 85 of Topology, Second Ed., by Munkres, he draws the open interval $(a\times b , c\times d)$. I found it a little counterintuitive.
Can you explain why is it that way? And why is it not bounded.
[Here is a screenshot of the relevant page. See Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzokj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of the lexicographic order.

So suppose (as in the first picture) that $a < c$.

Then $(x,y) \in (a \times b, c \times d)$ iff $(a,b) < (x,y)$ and $(x,y) < (c,d)$, by the definition of an open interval. Here the order $<$ on points is from the lexicographic order, where $(a,b) < (x,y)$ iff $a < x$ (the first coordinate determines the order) or $a = x$ and $b < y$ (in case the first coordinates are equal, the second coordinate determines the order).

In particular this contains all points $(e,f)$ where $a < e < c$. In that case, regardless of the value of $f$, the first coordinate already says that $(e,f)$ lies between $(a,b)$ and $c,d)$. This accounts for the vertical lines you see. We also get all $x$ with $x=a$ and $b < y$ (as $x=a$ garantuees being smaller than $(c,d)$), and $b < y$ that it's larger than $(a,b)$) and all points with $x=c$ and $y < d$, similarly.

Answer (score 0):

This is imminent from the *dicitionary order* imposed on $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$. You used
$$(a,b) <_\text{dict} (c,d) :\Leftrightarrow a<_{\mathbb R}c \text{ or } (a=c \text{ and } b<_{\mathbb R}d)$$
Then the notion of an interval is
$$(x,y) = \{\ z\in \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\ |\ x <_\text{dict} z \text{ and } z <_\text{dict} y\ \}$$
If you unravel this intuitive definition, you end up with the illustrated intervals.
Where $<_\mathbb R$ means the usual order on $\mathbb R$ and $:\Leftrightarrow$ is shorthand for *is defined by*.